# Vuejs 3 v-tables-3 customize filter text

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm learning Vue 3 and I'm using [vue3-tables](https://github.com/monofor/vue-tables-3). I read the documentation, but I don't find any example on how to customise the filter text. In the table header there is text input to filter content of the column and want to customize the default text : Filter by [Column name].

My use case is very simple:

```
<v-client-table :data="items1" :columns="columns1" :options="table_option">
                            <template #action="props">
                                <div class="actions text-center">
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" @click="openUser(props.row)" class="edit">
                                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24"
                                             viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor"
                                             stroke-width="2"
                                             stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"
                                             class="feather feather-edit"
                                             data-v-b121048b="">
                                            <path
                                                d="M11 4H4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v14a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h14a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-7"></path>
                                            <path
                                                d="M18.5 2.5a2.121 2.121 0 0 1 3 3L12 15l-4 1 1-4 9.5-9.5z"></path>
                                        </svg>
                                    </a>
                                    |
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" @click="openUser(props.row)" class="cancel">
                                        <svg
                                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                                            width="24"
                                            height="24"
                                            viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                                            fill="none"
                                            stroke="currentColor"
                                            stroke-width="1.5"
                                            stroke-linecap="round"
                                            stroke-linejoin="round"
                                            class="feather feather-x-circle table-cancel"
                                        >
                                            <circle cx="12" cy="12" r="10"></circle>
                                            <line x1="15" y1="9" x2="9" y2="15"></line>
                                            <line x1="9" y1="9" x2="15" y2="15"></line>
                                        </svg>
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            </template>
                        </v-client-table>
```

The code :

```
const items1 = ref([]);
    const columns1 = ref(["FirstName", "LastName", "action"]);

    // let dt;
    const table_option = ref({

        perPage: 10,
        perPageValues: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        skin: "table table-striped",
        columnsClasses: {

            action: "actions text-center"
        },

        headings: {

            FirstName: firstName,
            LastName: lastName,
            action: "",
        },

        pagination: {

            nav: "scroll",
            chunk: 5
        },

        texts: {

            count: t("Results") + " {from} " + t("of") + " {to}, " + t("Total") + " : {count}",
            filter: "",
            filterPlaceholder: t("Search"),
            limit: "Results:",
        },

        resizableColumns: false,

        sortable: ["FirstName", "LastName"],

        sortIcon: {

            base: "sort-icon-none",
            up: "sort-icon-asc",
            down: "sort-icon-desc",
        },

        filterByColumn: true,
        filterable: ["FirstName", "LastName"]
    });

    onMounted(() => {

        getUsers().then(() => {

            items1.value = users.value;
        }).catch(error => {

            console.log(error);
        });
    });

    const openUser = (item) => {

        router.push("/user/" + item.ID);
        // alert("ID: " + item.ID + ", Name: " + item.FirstName + " " + item.LastName);
    };
```

Any help will appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide the link to documentation. There are many table plugins for Vue3. I cannot find one using `<v-client-table>` tag.

Comment: @Tolbxela https://github.com/monofor/vue-tables-3

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the text, then use

```
 texts: {
    filter: "Filter by [Column name]" 
  },
```

If you want to set it dynamically, then you will need to implement a [custom filter](https://github.com/monofor/vue-tables-3#client-side-filters), which sets the `texts.filter` label.

Playground demonstrates changing of filter's label text.

```js
Vue.use(VueTables.ClientTable);

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    columns: ['name', 'code', 'uri'],
    data: getData(),
    options: {
      headings: {
        name: 'Country Name',
        code: 'Country Code',
        uri: 'View Record'
      },
      texts: {
        filter: "Filter by [Column name]" 
      },
      editableColumns:['name'],
      sortable: ['name', 'code'],
      filterable: ['name', 'code']
    }
  }
});

function getData() {
  return [{
    code: "ZW",
    name: "Zimbabwe",
    created_at: "2015-04-24T01:46:50.459583",
    updated_at: "2015-04-24T01:46:50.459593",
    uri: "http://api.lobbyfacts.eu/api/1/country/245",
    id: 245
  }, {
    code: "ZM",
    name: "Zambia",
    created_at: "2015-04-24T01:46:50.457459",
    updated_at: "2015-04-24T01:46:50.457468",
    uri: "http://api.lobbyfacts.eu/api/1/country/244",
    id: 244
  }, {
    code: "YE",
    name: "Yemen",
    created_at: "2015-04-24T01:46:50.454731",
    updated_at: "2015-04-24T01:46:50.454741",
    uri: "http://api.lobbyfacts.eu/api/1/country/243",
    id: 243
  }];
}
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }

.VuePagination {
  text-align: center;
}

.vue-title {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.vue-pagination-ad {
  text-align: center;
}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-eye-open {
  width: 16px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

th:nth-child(3) {
  text-align: center;
}

.VueTables__child-row-toggler {
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.VueTables__child-row-toggler--closed::before {
  content: "+";
}

.VueTables__child-row-toggler--open::before {
  content: "-";
}

[v-cloak] {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div id="app" v-cloak>
 <v-client-table :columns="columns" v-model="data" :options="options">
    <a slot="uri" slot-scope="props" target="_blank" :href="props.row.uri" class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></a>

    <div slot="child_row" slot-scope="props">
      The link to {{props.row.name}} is <a :href="props.row.uri">{{props.row.uri}}</a>
    </div>

    <div slot="name" slot-scope="{row, update, setEditing, isEditing, revertValue}">
      <span @click="setEditing(true)" v-if="!isEditing()">
        <a>{{row.name}}</a>
      </span>
      <span v-else>
        <input type="text" v-model="row.name">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" @click="update(row.name); setEditing(false)">Submit</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" @click="revertValue(); setEditing(false)">Cancel</button>
      
      </span>
    </div>
  </v-client-table>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.7.14/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/matfish2/vue-tables-2/master/dist/vue-tables-2.min.js"></script>
```